# OR in Regexp: why Regexp does not find elements inside the list of variants?

Tags: python, regex

I have a strings like: 'I got **11 bananas** yesterday'.
I need to get the number of fruits and fruits themselves. For example, '11 bananas' from the string above.

My code is:

```py
s1 = 'I got 11 oranges yesterday'
s2 = 'I got 11 bananas yesterday'
regex = re.compile('\d+ oranges|bananas|pencils')
results1 = re.findall(regex, s1) # returns [11 oranges], it's ok
results2 = re.findall(regex, s2) # returns [bananas], it's wrong
```

It finds what I need if the fruit's name is first in the list of possible fruits, but fails with the fruit inside the list.

Where's the mistake? My brain is broken

Comment: You should group the fruits `\d+ (?:oranges|bananas|pencils)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the priority of the `|` operator, what you wrote means

```
(\d+ oranges) OR (bananas) OR (pencils)
```

You need parenthesis around the fruits

```
\d+ (?:oranges|bananas|pencils)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not change the result. As wrote @Thefourthbird above, we need '\d+ (?:oranges|bananas|pencils)' pattern